# iOS Post to Facebook publish screen doesn't show after authentication

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults, facebook-ios-sdk, sbjson

Alrighty. I have a button (below) where I take some info from an app and I post it to the users FB feed.

It almost never works the first time. Them, it will usually work pretty well after that. What happens is, when I press the button it tells me that I already gave the app permission to use FB (which I would like to only have to see the first time, not every time). Then when I press OK from there it will either go back to the app, or it will go to show me the page where I can actually post to my wall (which is what I want).

Im trying different things to get this to work more consistently. Is there something here that would be causing this behavior?

```
-(IBAction)fbButton:(id)sender {

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:permissions];
        [permissions release];
    }

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    //Post to Wall

    NSString *poopDollas = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                         @"sometext $%@!",dollas.text];

    SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

    // The action links to be shown with the post in the feed
    NSArray* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      @"Get Started",@"name",@"http://www.facebook.com/pages/xx/204640386498567",@"link", nil], nil];
    NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
    // Dialog parameters
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"DM", @"name",
                                   poopDollas, @"caption",
                                   @"sometext", @"description",
                                   @"http://www.facebook.com/pages/xx/204640386498567", @"link",
                                   @"http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7185/6999841878_e66a8e00fc_t.jpg", @"picture",
                                   actionLinksStr, @"actions",
                                   nil];

    FBDialog *delegate = (FBDialog *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:(id <FBDialogDelegate>)delegate];
}
```

Comment: A couple of comments: 1) Please upgrade your copy of SBJson. The class you're using was split into two many years ago; many, *many* important bugs have been fixed since. 2) Please upgrade your code to use ARC. 3) Please use dictionary static initialiser for readability (`@{ @"key": @"value" }`).

Answer (score 0):

I took out the

```
[facebook authorize:permissions];
[permissions release];
```

In that first IF statement and my problems seem to be solved..